# Python find match/unmatch string from two variables

Tags: python

Need to identify the matched/unmatched string from both the variables. i am able to get the data based on the respective index only. I need the both variables to check all the data and produce the result.

```
apdb = {'AP Database': [{'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'varagu'},
                 {'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'thinai'},
                 {'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'kambu'},
                 {'AP Type': '205H',
                  'Name': 'keppai'}]
        }

apdb1 = {'AP Database': [{'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'kudhiravali'},
                 {'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'kambu'},
                 {'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'solam'},
                 {'AP Type': '205H',
                  'Name': 'keppai'},
                 {'AP Type': '205H',
                  'Name': 'rice'}]
        }


ap_database = apdb.get('AP Database')
ap_database1 = apdb1.get('AP Database')


ap1 = []
ap2 = []

for ap_detail , ap_detail1 in zip(ap_database, ap_database1):
    str1= ap_detail.__getitem__('Name')
    str2= ap_detail1.__getitem__('Name')

    if str1 in str2:
        ap1.append((str1, 'Matched'))
    else:
        ap1.append((str1, 'Unmatched'))

    if str2 in str1:
        ap2.append((str2, 'Matched'))
    else:
        ap2.append((str2, 'Unmatched'))

print (ap1)
print (ap2)
```

Result which it gives is below

```
 [('varagu', 'Unmatched'), ('thinai', 'Unmatched'), ('kambu', 'Unmatched'), ('keppai', 'Matched')]
[('kudhiravali', 'Unmatched'), ('kambu', 'Unmatched'), ('solam', 'Unmatched'), ('keppai', 'Matched')]
```

Actually the word 'Kambu' is available on both the strings, but the result is showing unmatched, it need to be matched and also str2 got additional word 'rice', which is not showing in the result need that also to be displayed as 'Not available'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
>>> apdb = {'AP Database': [{'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'varagu'},
                 {'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'thinai'},
                 {'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'kambu'},
                 {'AP Type': '205H',
                  'Name': 'keppai'}]
        }
>>> apdb1 = {'AP Database': [{'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'kudhiravali'},
                 {'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'kambu'},
                 {'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'solam'},
                 {'AP Type': '205H',
                  'Name': 'keppai'},
                 {'AP Type': '205H',
                  'Name': 'rice'}]
        }

# Extract the 'Name's and make 'set's
>>> ap_database = set([d['Name'] for d in apdb['AP Database']])
>>> ap_database1 = set([d['Name'] for d in apdb1['AP Database']])

# Intersection of two sets are the matched items
>>> ap_result = [(e, 'Matched') for e in ap_database.intersection(ap_database1)]
>>> ap_result1 = ap_result[:]

# Difference of two sets are umnatched
>>> ap_result += [(e,'Unmatched') for e in ap_database-ap_database1]
>>> ap_result1 += [(e,'Unmatched') for e in ap_database1-ap_database]

# Desired results
>>> ap_result
[('keppai', 'Matched'), ('kambu', 'Matched'), ('thinai', 'Unmatched'), ('varagu', 'Unmatched')]
>>> ap_result1
[('keppai', 'Matched'), ('kambu', 'Matched'), ('solam', 'Unmatched'), ('rice', 'Unmatched'), ('kudhiravali', 'Unmatched')]
```